# Convert string to Aspose.Cells.Name

Tags: c#, type-conversion, aspose, aspose-cells

I am trying to check, if the name of the sheet already is in the other workbook.
I am currently trying it like this:

```cs
if (tempWb.Worksheets.Names.Contains(ibbWs.Worksheets[index].Name))
{
...
}
```

How can I fix that or convert a string into a Aspose.Cells.Name object?

Comment: can you please add your error message also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply check whether a given Name is null or not, so you may write your own code accordingly for your needs. See the sample code segment for your reference:
e.g

**Sample code:**

```
------------
Name name = workbook.Worksheets.Names["yournamestring"];
if (name == null)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Not found");
                else
                    Debug.WriteLine("found" );
                    //...........Your code goes here.
  -------
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.